# Image in backgound mode get automatically hidden fro SAPUI5 V1.38.39

Tags: sapui5

**Framework :** SAPUI5 V1.38.39
**Problem :** when I make an image with mode="Background" the image is not displayed in the view, i took example on [Sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Image/sample/sap.m.sample.ImageModeBackground/code/view/Image.view.xml) to make this and in sample it is displayed
**Code:**

```
<html:Div>
    <Image src="img/bg_icons.png" mode="Background" backgroundPosition="center" backgroundSize="cover" width="100%" visible="true">
        <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
        </layoutData>
    </Image>
    <core:Fragment fragmentName="my.namespace.view.fragment.Milestone" type="XML"/>
</html:Div>
```

The fragment contain only some text which should appear on the image
**The result on the "element"**:

```
<span id="__image0" data-sap-ui="__image0" class="sapMImg" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" alt="" style="background-size: cover; background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%; background-image: url(&quot;https://webidetesting.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/~1611310755000~/webapp/img/bg_icons.png&quot;);"></span>
```

**Hypothesis on the problem origin :**
I suppose the problem come from `aria-hidden="true"` but I have not idea why `aria-hidden="true"` is there.

Comment: You're looking at the sample from the latest version, currently 1.85.3. The samples for 1.38.39 are [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.39/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Image/preview) and the API is [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.39/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Image.html). Not sure if it matters, `mode` is available on that version too but you never know.